# problems with dev_appserver datastore file

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a simple question, I been playing with dev_appserver testing my Go app locally.
I saved some keys:

```
client, err = datastore.NewClient(ctx, utils.ProjectID)
key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, KindSpace, "", id, nil)
if _, err := client.Put(ctx, key, value); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

However, When connecting to: `http://localhost:8000/datastore` my datastore is empty.
I then tried to retrieve the keys from inside my code using:

```
client, err = datastore.NewClient(ctx, utils.ProjectID)
entity := new(Space)
key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, KindSpace, "", id, nil)
if err := client.Get(ctx, key, entity); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

and indeed it returned the keys I saved. Do you have any idea what do I miss? Does it have something to do with the database namespace maybe?

Is there anyway to read the local data base from the terminal?

Comment: What is `client` type above?

Comment: @abhink added definition of client